# wrap a function in emacs lisp

Tags: elisp

In 1987, I wrote the code I'm going to paste in a moment. The mechanism used here to capture the initial function binding of switch-to-buffer doesn't work any more, resulting in infinite recursion. I guess that there's a right way to do this sort of thing now, could someone please fill me in?

```
(defvar *real-buffer-switcher* nil)

(defun improve-buffer-switch ()
  (if *real-buffer-switcher* nil
    (setq *real-buffer-switcher* (symbol-function 'switch-to-buffer))
    (fset 'switch-to-buffer 'better-switch-to-buffer)
    t))

;(setq *real-buffer-switcher* (symbol-function 'switch-to-buffer))

(defun better-switch-to-buffer (buffer-name &optional no-record)
  (interactive "p") ; c-u c-x b goes ahead and creates. Note that
            ; buffer-name is fraudulently named so as to permit
            ; non-interactive calls.
  ;; first, filter out the noninteractive case.
  (if (or (stringp buffer-name)
      (bufferp buffer-name))
      (funcall *real-buffer-switcher* buffer-name no-record)
    ;; interactive. Numeric arg?
    (funcall *real-buffer-switcher*
         (read-buffer "Buffer name: "
              (other-buffer (current-buffer))
              (= buffer-name 1)))))

(improve-buffer-switch)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the code that used to work no longer works (unless your `*real-buffer-switcher*` somehow got set to `'better-buffer-switcher`.  Is there any reason why you don't just bind <kbd>C-x b</kbd> the the routine you really want and leave `switch-to-buffer` alone?

Like so:

```
(defun better-switch-to-buffer (buffer-name &optional no-record)
  (interactive "p") 
  ;; interactive. Numeric arg?
  (switch-to-buffer
   (read-buffer "Buffer name: "
                (other-buffer (current-buffer))
                (= buffer-name 1))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") 'better-switch-to-buffer)
```

Comment: It was a long time ago. I think there was a reason.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the right answer to my question is defadvice.

Comment: That was my first thought, but it's total overkill if you can't figure out why you did things the convoluted way you did originally.